# .net MVC Razor. Поиск мест использования переменных в cshtml файлах в Razor коде

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Использую VS 2022. Работаю в проекте с MVC. При поиске ссылок на переменную находит их все во всех проектах в решении кроме файлов cshtml в Razor коде. Причём, если найти какое-то такое место, то VS его увидит и уже будет отображать в списке ссылок. Кто-то может знает расширения для VS или другие способы, которые помогают с этим и сразу находят все места использования переменной в Razor коде?